# SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal, в python

Tags: python

Насколько я понимаю, ошибка происходит из-за `\/` или `,`. Как это исправить?

```
link = f"https://www.soccerstand.com/res/image/data/{(item.split('","detail_link"')[0].split("data\/")[1])}"
```

Comment: А можно и просто экранировать все внутренние двойные кавычки `"` -> `\"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас сейчас в строке в двойных кавычках используются другие двойные кавычки, которые прерывают эту строку (завершают ее), т.е. строка фактически такая:

```
f"https://www.soccerstand.com/res/image/data/{(item.split('"
```

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что в этой строке не закрыты фигурные скобки, и в целом текст от начала фигурных скобок до первых встреченных двойных кавычек не является синтаксически корректным (завершенным) выражением, в процессе его парсинга встретился конец строки (EOL - end of line).

Решение простое - не пытаться впихнуть все в f-строку, а вычислять подставляемое значение отдельно:

```
part = item.split('","detail_link"')[0].split("data\/")[1]
link = f"https://www.soccerstand.com/res/image/data/{part}"
```